# Java records and the single class per file limit

Tags: java, java-14, java-record

I'm trying out the new records feature with java 14, currently in preview.
I know that in Java one has to have exactly one public class per file but with the new record syntax being so nice and short it just seem wasteful to have a bunch of files each with a single line of code in them.

In particular I wanted to try to model a simple AST like this, and I think that having everything together in one file really improves readability and comprehension.

```java
package com.company;

public interface Expression {
}

public record IntExp(int value) implements Expression {
}

public record AddExp(Expression left, Expression right) implements Expression {
}

public record SubtractExp(Expression left, Expression right) implements Expression {
}

// Etc..
```

But unfortunately this will not compile.
So my question is:

**Is there any way around this limitation or some way to keep code like this all in one place?**

Comment: *"keep code like this all in one place"* ... that's what packages are for.

Comment: "*I think that having everything together in one file really improves readability and comprehension*" FWIW, I don't. The point of any well-designed interface is that its potential implementations are infinite. Just because you have 3 implementations in one file doesn't mean I can ignore the fact that other implementations might exist. Also, I'm assuming your interface and implementations actually have at least one method with an implementation, so the case where there are just 4 lines of definitions is quite contrived.

Comment: @Michael You should read about [*sealed types*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/360)

Comment: @fps What makes you think I haven't?

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I didn't mean to mock you. This: *"The point of any well-designed interface is that its potential implementations are infinite"* made me think that, maybe, you hadn't read about sealed types. My point is that sealed types seem to be what the OP is asking about

Comment: @fps yes sealed types seem to be what I am looking for! in fact I was basically trying to recreate sum types from functional languages.. if you put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inner classes, along with [*sealed types*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/360) seem to be what you're after. Java 15 has introduced sealed types as a preview feature.

You've stated that you wanted to model an AST in one single file. An AST is *exhaustive*. And this *exhaustiveness* can be modeled with inner classes **and** sealed types.

In your particular example, if you define the super type along with all its *permitted* subtypes in the same compilation unit (with the subtypes being inner classes), the compiler will automatically infer the `permits` for you:

```
public sealed interface Expression {

    record IntExp(int value) implements Expression { }

    record AddExp(Expression left, Expression right) implements Expression { }

    record SubtractExp(Expression left, Expression right) implements Expression { }
}
```

Here, the compiler will automatically infer `IntExp`, `AddExp` and `SubtractExp` as `permits` and won't allow any other types (declared in any other compilation unit) to neither extend nor implement the `Expression` interface.

Comment: Sealed classes have nothing to do with what the OP asked

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov They have something to do, because the compiler won't allow an implementing class outside the compilation unit

Comment: "because the compiler won't allow an implementing class outside the compilation unit", but that's not something OP had as a requirement. They only wanted to have several public classes in one file. We can _assume_ that there won't be any other implementation somewhere else, but it hasn't be stated by OP.

Comment: @Tom OP wants an AST in one single file. An AST is *exhaustive*. And this exhaustiveness can be modeled with inner classes **and** sealed types

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Wow, did you misread that one :)  The answerer here clearly discerned what was really being asked, and the OP even said "that's what I was looking for."  So maybe you need to tune your "that's not what was asked" filter by a few notches.

Comment: For what its worth, we spent a fair amount of time dealing with the underlying concern the OP raised here in the design of sealed classes, because this question comes up most frequently when defining a tightly related group of data carrier classes, such as the nodes of an AST.  This use case -- where the records are nested inside the interface -- is rewarded by inference of the `permits` list, which you wouldn't get if you put them in one file each.  At one point we considered relaxing the restrictions on auxilliary classes, but found that it wasn't necessary, as this idiom does the trick.

Answer (score 7):

One obvious approach is to move the 'pre-defined' record classes into the interface:

```java
package com.company;

public interface Expression {
    record IntExp(int value) implements Expression {
    }

    record AddExp(Expression left, Expression right) implements Expression {
    }

    record SubtractExp(Expression left, Expression right) implements Expression {
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that you can still have separate source files that implement the interface if (for example) you have a particularly complicated type of expression.